Distant to be "were" in relative clause in "his trials and tribulations, which he claimed were his worst"

His trials and tribulations, which he claimed were his worst, would be more satisfactory if he actually took the time to organize his thoughts. Source

I rarely see this pattern as I more often encountered something like this

He claimed his trials and tribulations, which were his worst, ... (rearranged)

that I feel the former sentence is a bit confusing to me as were usually doesn't appear after several words.
Why is such construction allowed? To what extent is this construction permissible? It will be helpful if someone can give me a reference of why such to be (were) is licensed in this case.
Thank you.

You must surely see plenty of parenthetical clauses: My car, which is red, cost £5,000; his son, who he claimed to be a genius, played the piano at the party.

Compare  "The monster (which) you said you saw was only a shadow". which is optional. or "The monster he said was on the roof was only a raccoon".

to claim something is not something. It is not a pattern. It's just writing.

The symphony, which he claimed was his best, received no reaction in the press.

COMPARE

The symphony, which was his best, received no reaction in the press.

In the one with claim, it is he who is doing the claiming. In the one without it, it is the writer of the sentence who is saying it was his best.
Those independent clauses are fine. They just mean different things.

The movie, which the director admitted was not his best work, went on for four boring hours with battle scene after battle scene but little story.


Analyze this sequence of statements, paying special attention to the bolded clauses.
Phase 1: the map

Here is a map which I drew. It will show you the way.
-- OK, thanks.

Phase 2: the phone call

The bridge was washed out by heavy rains, and so I cannot follow the map which you drew. The map which you said would show me the way does not show the small roads. So I am lost now.

Even though you are asking about were, your question is not really about were. It is about "you claimed" and how that phrase fits into the relative clause.


His trials and tribulations, which he claimed were his worst, would be more satisfactory if he actually took the time to organize his thoughts.


He claimed his trials and tribulations, which were his worst, would be more satisfactory if he actually took the time to organize his thoughts.

The examples are fine but mean different things.  There were two things said, claimed, or written.
In the first example, it was the writer who said His trials and tribulations would be more satisfactory ...
The claim that these trials and tribulations
were the sufferer's worst was made by the sufferer himself.
In the second, it was the sufferer who claimed His trials and tribulations would be more satisfactory ...
The view that these trials and tribulations
were the sufferer's worst was the writer's.
We have a role switch in the two examples.
